# QC 1 on Mathematical Induction in 'Walk through Combinatorics'

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Use induction to prove that if a<sub>n</sub> = 1+2+···+n, then a<sub>n</sub> = n(n+1)/2,
for all positive integers n.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones yes it does. Seems like mine is a duplicate question. Should I delete it ?

Answer (score 0):

**The Initial Step.** a<sub>1</sub> = 1 and a<sub>1</sub> = 1(2)/2 = 1. Thus, the equation is true for n=1.

**The Inductive Step**. Let us assume the equation is true for n. Then,
1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2      ----**1**

Now, we have to prove the equation for n+1. i.e.
1+2+...+n+n+1 = (n+1)(n+2)/2      ----**2**

eqn **2**-**1**, we get
n+1 = (n+1)(n+2)/2 - n(n+1)/2         ----**3**
This is a true statement, and we know by inductive step that eqn **1** is a true statement. Adding both these statements, we get,
1+2+..+n+n+1 = n(n+1)/2 + (n+1)(n+2)/2 - n(n+1)/2 = **(n+1)(n+2)/2**
**Hence Proved**.